# CSS width 100% property is not being updated for my animation on screen orientation change

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-animations

As you can see in the following snippet, I have build a little carousel which rotates between 4 div items (*+1 which is a dublicate to achieve the looping effect, however thats not relevant for this question)*. I am setting the width of the container to be 500% and the width of each item to be 20% of the container. Then I use transform translate to move the container to it shows the next item.

All the above works perfectly fine, expect for when I change the screen orientation of my device. For some reason something is not being calculated correctly anymore and the items are being positions incorrectly. If i refresh the page, the width is calculated correctly again so it only occures after I have changed the orientation from the orientation that the page originally loaded in.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  --item-count: 5;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% * var(--item-count));
  height: 100px;
  animation: test_carousel calc(3000ms * var(--item-count)) infinite;
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100% / var(--item-count));
}
.item:nth-child(1) { background-color: blue; }
.item:nth-child(2) { background-color: skyblue; }
.item:nth-child(3) { background-color: purple; }
.item:nth-child(4) { background-color: red; }
.item:nth-child(5) { background-color: blue; }
@keyframes test_carousel {
  0% { transform: translateX(0%) }
  22% { transform: translateX(0%) }
  25% { transform: translateX(-20%) }
  47% { transform: translateX(-20%) }
  50% { transform: translateX(-40%) }
  72% { transform: translateX(-40%) }
  75% { transform: translateX(-60%) }
  97% { transform: translateX(-60%) }
  100% { transform: translateX(-80%) }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

PS: I have already tried changing to vw units and this did not work either unfortunatly

Comment: Maybe it's hard to tell because of the solid colors, but on my browsers if I resize or rotate it still looks ok.

Comment: @ITgoldman Which browser are you using? Because when I am viewing it on safari on my phone it does not work after I rotate the screen.